# Installing: partition

Tags: partitioning

I tried to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 in my computer. I have made the partition in Windows before I tried to install. So I already have the unallocated drive. But during the installation process, I have this notification:

"If you continue, the changes listed below will be written to the disks. Otherwise, you will be able to make further changes manually."

This notification was followed by the explanation about the partition table.

So, my question: is it normal to get such notification even though we already made partition in Windows before starting to install?

This is the information of the partition table from Ubuntu:

*The partition tables of the following devices are changed: SCI 1 (0,0,0) (sda)*

*The following partitions are going to be formated: partition #6 of SCSI 1 (0,0,0) (sda) as ext4; partision #7 SCI 1 (0,0,0) (sda) as swap*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal. The installer always displays this message.

Check the partition information before you proceed, and make sure that you're installing Ubuntu into the unallocation partition and that your Windows partition will not be affected or overwritten.

If you are unsure, then take a screenshot (or a photo) of the partitioner and post it on here, and we'll guide you if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Carl for your answer. I added some information in the question. I tried to upload the picture of the disk management, but it was rejected. It is said that I should have 10 reputation for posting a picture. Do you have suggestion where I can post the picture so that you can see it.

Comment: This is the link where you can get the photo of my disk management: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rq4ppphkys176np/20150225_190819.jpg?dl=0. And the information regarding partition from Ubuntu I have added it in my question above.

Comment: It looks about right, but to be sure, can you run the Ubuntu installation disk and take a photo of that?

Comment: Thanks Carl for trying to help. I have installed Ubuntu. I set the partition manually. No problem with the partition.